# Can it be that `sympy` is much, much slower than Mathematica?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, sympy

I'm reproducing Mathematica results using `Sympy`, and I'm new to the latter, so I might be doing things wrong. However, I noticed that some stuff that took a minute at max using Mathematica is just taking forever (read: did not finish after I started it an hour ago) in sympy. That applies both to `Simplify()`, and `solve()`. Am I doing something wrong, or is that really the case?

I'll attach my `solve()` case:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing()

p, r, c, p, y, Lambda = sp.symbols('p r c p y Lambda')

F = sp.Symbol('F')
eta1 = lambda p: 1/(1-sp.exp(-Lambda) * sp.exp(-Lambda)*(sp.exp(Lambda) - 1 - Lambda))
eta2 = lambda p: 1/(1-sp.exp(-Lambda)) * sp.exp(-Lambda)/(1-F) * (sp.exp(Lambda*(1- F)) - 1 - Lambda*(1-F))

eta = lambda p: 1 - eta1(p) + eta2(p)
etaOfR = sp.limit(eta(p), F,  1)

S = lambda p: eta(p)*y/p*(p-c)
SOfR = etaOfR*y/r*(r-c)
sp.solve(S(p)-SOfR, F)
```

*The corresponding Mathematica code*:

```
ClearAll[r, p, lambda, a, A, c, eta, f, y, constant1, constant2, eta, \
etaOfR]
constant1[lambda_] := Exp[-lambda]/(1 - Exp[-lambda]);
constant2[lambda_] := constant1[lambda]*(Exp[lambda] - 1 - lambda);
eta[lambda_, f_] := 
  1 - constant2[lambda] + 
   constant1[lambda]*(Exp[lambda*(1 - f)] - 1 - lambda*(1 - f)) ;
etaOfR[lambda_] := Limit[eta[lambda, f], f -> 1];
expression1[lambda_, f_] := 
  y/p (p - c) eta[lambda, f] == y/r (r - c) etaOfR[lambda];

Solve[expression1[lambda, f], f] // FullSimplify
```

Output:

```
{{f -> (-(1 + lambda) p r + 
    c (lambda p + r) + (c - 
       p) r ProductLog[-E^(((-c lambda p + (c (-1 + lambda) + 
           p) r)/((c - p) r)))])/(lambda (c - p) r)}}
```

Comment: My initial feeling is that Mathematica is likely to be a lot better than Sympy at the moment, given the massive head start it has.

Comment: why are you defining functions with `lambda`?

Comment: @MaxNoe because the tutorial didn't mention how to define functions, I googled around and saw people on the internet doing this.

Comment: I also share chthonicdaemon's feelings. It all comes down to what algorithms are under the hood (and how optimised they are) to do the assigned tasks. I've had to switch to Maple once because sympy both couldn't integrate some complex functions, but also for the problems it could, it would do so at a crawling speed.

Comment: To my understanding sympy does not need these to be functions. Just use your symbols.

Comment: The above code does not make much sense. I tried to solve the problem, but it looks mathematically wrong. See here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/jankoslavic/0ad7d5c2731d425dabb3

Please publish Mathematica code and I will try to help you.

Comment: @jankos I've added the mathematica code

Comment: Unless you plan to use multiple values for `P`, there's no need to use a lambda. Just define the expression with `p`. Even if you do plan to do that, it is often better with SymPy to create an expression with a Symbol and use `subs` to replace the Symbol with something else if you want to evaluate it.

Comment: Regarding `Simplify`: simplification is not a well-defined thing, so huge performance differences, and well as big differences in the result can completely be expected.  Just think about the difference between `FullSimplify` and `Simplify`.  The former might be much slower even when it gives the same result as the latter.  (This doesn't apply the same way to equation solving.)

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to do it is:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
p, r, c, p, y, lam, f = symbols('p r c p y lambda f')
constant1 = exp(-lam) / (1 - exp(-lam))
constant2 = constant1 * (exp(lam) -  1 - lam)
eta = 1 - constant2 + constant1 * (exp(lam * (1-f)) - 1 - lam * (1 - f))
etaOfR = limit(eta, f,  1)
expression1 = Eq(y / p * (p - c) * eta, 
             y / r * (r - c) * etaOfR)
solve(expression1, f)
```

You can also check the notebook here:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/jankoslavic/0ad7d5c2731d425dabb3

The results is equal to the one from Mathematica (see last line) and Sympy performance is comparable.

Comment: 30s in sympy and 1s in Mathematica is not what I would call comparable. Certik is porting sympy to C++ for a reason.